# Create new instances of 'animation' (CSS property on div) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I have an element with class feedback, and upon when a JavaScript function is called, the feedbackAnimate animation is added.

```
document.querySelector('.feedback').classList.add('feedbackAnimate');
```

I want the animation to play each time the function is called, but NOT 'delete'/reset the original animation. I'm guessing I'll need to create new div instances, is that right? How do I do that from JavaScript?

Animation CSS:

```
.feedback {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 20;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
}

.feedbackAnimate {
  animation-name: removeLayer;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform: translateY(-300%);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes removeLayer {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-300%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the animation. Show us what your animation looks like in terms of code.

Comment: Hi @WaisKamal, I've added the animation CSS to main post

Comment: add the javascript "calling" code as well and HTML that calls that function

Comment: @Vepthy, the JS is just what I have above, inside a function `function incrementScore(){

  document.querySelector('.feedback').classList.add('feedbackAnimate'); }`

The HTML is just `<div class="feedback"></div>`

Comment: What you are saying is impossible to do. How would you like to move the feedback element down everytime by 300% of its height without resetting the previous shift? Your element will soon run out of screen space.

Comment: Do you want to make element go up and down or do you want each time you click on something to make the div go 300% down?

Comment: WaisKamal, @Vepthy, sorry - don't think I explained clearly enough. I want an animation (little element to fade and move up - haven't finalised the animation CSS above) to play every time the function is called, and if the function is called again before the first animation has finished, I want a new instance of the animation to play, without affecting the first animation, which should be allowed to complete then disappear when the animation has finished

Comment: It's impossible to do that on one element. You can do it by making a new (identical) element and doing animation on it. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Vepthy, yeah, how can I do that with JS?

Comment: Wait a bit, I'll try to make it.